# Custom object display in JSON

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using only jersey and not jackson to create a REST api. I've two model objects,

```
public class Course {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Teacher teacher;
}

public class Teacher {

    private int id;
    private String givenName;
    private String familyName;

}
```

I'm creating a service and returning a List of Course objects,

```
public List<Course> getAll(){
        return db.getCourseList();
    }
```

The display is as expected,

```
[{"id":101,"name":"Introduction to Java","teacher":{"familyName":"Bar","givenName":"Foo","id":201}},{"id":102,"name":"Intermediate Java","teacher":{"familyName":"Prank","givenName":"Foo","id":202}}]
```

Now I want to customize my JSON object to display in the following format, with only the teacher ID.

```
[{"id":"100","name":"Introduction to Java","teacherId":"201"},{"id":"101","name":"Intermediate Java","teacherId":"201"}
```

So this is the view model that I designed.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CourseTeacherIdView {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int teacherId;

    CourseTeacherIdView(){

    }

    public CourseTeacherIdView(int id, String name, int teacherId){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.teacherId = teacherId;
    }

}
```

And I use this method to return the List of view objects.

```
public List<CourseTeacherIdView> getAll(){
        List<Course> list = db.getCourseList();
        List<CourseTeacherIdView> viewList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Iterator<Course> itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
            Course c = (Course) itr.next();
            viewList.add(new CourseTeacherIdView(c.getId(), c.getName(), c.getTeacher().getId()));
        }
        return viewList;
    }
```

This is the result that I get.

```
[{},{},{}]
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Actually fixed it. Apparently if the class has no getters and setters this is how the objects are printed. I added the getters and setters and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with Jackson and creating a custom serializer like the following:

```
public class CourseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Course> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Course value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeStartObject();

        Field[] fields = value.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object obj = field.get(value);
                if (obj instanceof Teacher) {
                    Teacher teacher = (Teacher) obj;
                    gen.writeStringField("teacherId", String.valueOf(teacher.getId()));
                } else {
                    gen.writeStringField(field.getName(), obj.toString());
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Course.class, new CourseSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher(123, "teacher1", "surename1");
    Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher(234, "teacher2", "surename2");
    Course course1 = new Course(1, "course1", teacher1);
    Course course2 = new Course(2, "course2", teacher2);
    List<Course> courses = Arrays.asList(new Course[]{course1, course2});

    String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(courses);
}
```

Output:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "course1",
    "teacherId": "123"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "course2",
    "teacherId": "234"
}]
```

Comment: So I populate my List with CourseSerializer objects?

Comment: No, you don't change anything regarding your current list. You just need to register the serializer on the mapper and you can simply serialize a list of Courses like before. This is using Jackson btw.

Comment: Well I'm not using Jackson.

Comment: You didn't specify that... anyway I am not familiarized with Gson or other frameworks, so if you can't use Jackson I suggest you wait for someone else to opt in.

Comment: Btw, you can easily use Jackson with Jersey.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help you with JAX-RS (should be the default json provider for Jersey). I suggest you look for the equivalent custom serializer for JAX-RS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could either create new view model representation with only the id and map each object in the list to it, or use @jsonignore on not relevant fields (if jersey is using Jackson). Or even retrieve only the ids from the db. Depends on use case.